# Managing two projects with Mercurial in one inetpub directory

Tags: laravel-4, mercurial, iis-6, atlassian-sourcetree

UPDATE:  I missed a layer in the directory structure (the laravel parent folder, specifically).  I'm quite embarassed...

I have a Mercurial repository tracking a Laravel project I've built under 
IIS 6, with the following directory structure:

```
inetpub
|--laravel
   |--app
   |--bootstrap
   |--vendor
|--wwwroot
   |--Project
   |--OtherScript (set to ignore in .hgignore)
```

I now want to begin work on a second project, and have modified the directory structure accordingly:

```
inetpub
|--laravel
   |--app
   |--app2
   |--bootstrap
   |--bootstrap2
   |--vendor
|--wwwroot
   |--Project
   |--Project2
   |--OtherScript (set to ignore in .hgignore)
```

I've added the "2" folders to the .hgignore for the original repository, but I'm having trouble working out how to set up a separate repository that ignores the original project folders, and will just track the 2s.  I thought I could just create a new repository covering inetpub that uses a different .hgignore file, but when I create the repository it automatically references the .hgignore file established for the first repository.  I'm presumably missing something, but I'm not sure what.  How can I make this work?  The project is just starting, so restructuring is entirely viable if that's necessary.

Comment: I realized after reviewing my comment that I'd screwed up my directory structure, leaving out the parent `laravel` directory containing `app`, `bootstrap` and `vendor`.  I've fixed it in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two repositories residing in the same directory does not work.
There are several options which might suit your needs, though:

a) Use a parent directory in which you organize your projects in sub-directories. This is usually the recommended the standard approach with mercurial; each of the sub-direcoties becomes an independent repository. The parent directory would not contain much, but can be made a separate repository as well, if desired.

b) Use branches for different projects. Switching between projects then requires switching branches in your project.

c) You can extend option (a) and consider using sub-repositories or guest repositories. They come with some rough edges, thus their use will need careful consideration. You can also start with option (a) and convert it to option (c) at any later time. See [Subrepository](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository) and also the links in the 'Alternatives' section.

Comment: My repository reflects the default directory structures of laravel and IIS: 

1) the files in a laravel project are split into the main application code (`app`) written by me, bootstrap code for initializing the app (`bootstrap`), and outside libraries (`vendor`) under the `laravel` parent directory.

2) I want to include the web-accessible content in `Project` (e.g. .js files) under version control alongside the PHP code in the `laravel` subdirectories

From what you're saying, I need to create a main repository, and then add `app`, `Project` et al to it as subrepos.  Does that sound right?

Comment: If the directory structure is given by how laravel works, then yes.

Using sub-repositories for the single directories might be the best choice, if you don't want one big repository for everything

Comment: I've tried kicking the tires on it, and I think it's going to work.  It probably helps that I'm the only person working with this codebase, so as long as it makes sense to me it will do.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

As an aid to others fumbling their way to a better understanding of doing this with Sourcetree, here's a quick overview of what I've done based on planetmaker's advice.

1. Used the "Clone/New" option to created individual new repositories from the `app`, `bootstrap` and `Project` folders (I've determined that there's no point in tracking `vendor`).
2. Committed the contents of each of those repositories.
3. Created a new `Project_Repository` folder outside of `inetpub`
4. Created a new Repository from the `Project_Repository` folder
5. With the Project_Repository tab open, selected "Add Subdirectory" from the Repository menu, and selected the `app` directory.
6. Repeat 4. for `bootstrap` and `Project`

After doing that, I have a current copy of the content of all 3 directories in the Project_Repository folder, along with the appropriate .hg files.  I'm optimistic that this will work well for Project2 as well.